# Tag Challenge! May 27 to June 9: Character Development, Narrative, Mythology - RESULTS

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion, contest

Welcome to stage 2 of our tag challenge! [Stage 1 was very successful](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2015/33442) so we [decided to keep going](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2016/33442), with a few slight changes.

The tags:

- [character-development](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) started the challenge at 462
- [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative) started at 121 questions
- [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) started at 12 questions

At the end of the two weeks:

- [character-development](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) reached 467 questions
- [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative) reached 155 questions
- [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) reached 16 questions.

---

## Results

To be fair, the great winner of this challenge is the [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative), that received - both by new questions and retagging - a push of 34 questions towards the 200-mark. [character-development](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) and [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) were a lot slower, but it's worth noting that [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) is a very specific topic. Nonetheless, it has generated some good questions and discussion in the site.

Congratulations to our winner: **NofP** who used two of the tags and linked their question with the writing exercise.

Honourable mentions to: **celtschk** who was able to combine two of the proposed tags in one question, and **Liquid** who asked two questions with one tag each.

You are all deserving of your sacks of bragging rights, use them wisely.

<strike>We'll come back shortly with another set of tags, so stay in touch!</strike> The [new tag challenge](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2043/33442) is now up!

## TAGS OF THE FORTNIGHT PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for two weeks, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or more of the tags.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the challenge, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.
- Re-tagging old questions on these tags is encouraged but keep it at a reasonable rate. We don't want to flood the homepage.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use multiple tags in the same question.
- A third if you manage to tie a question in to the latest [writing exercise](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-exercise).

---

**Notes:**

- The contest started Monday?  But it's Tuesday (Wednesday for some people)!  Shush, it's the first week.
- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this challenge's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal of this challenge is:

  - Increase overall question rates toward 10 questions per day.
  - Get us to the Generalist badge by having 40 tags with over 200 questions.
  - Promote tags that may otherwise be lost or forgotten.
- Each fortnight we'll have thee tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

  - One tag will be a high popularity tag to increase participation in the challenge.
  - One tag will start the challenge between 100 and 200 questions to move us toward generalist.
  - One tag will be freely chosen by the challenge poster. Though tags from the [new tab](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) are encouraged.

Comment: I like this version of the tag challenge.  Thanks for doing it.

Comment: Cool.  I fixed one typo but I will note that you've changed this to a fortnight challenge but still say "week" a few time in the rules.  Don't know if you want to change that.

Comment: @Cyn Thanks for catching that, I thought I got them all.

Comment: @linksassin I went ahead and wrote the results, but feel free to edit and make changes. If you don't have time, I can take over the challenge for next 2-weeks. Your call.

Comment: @Liquid Thanks for doing that. New challenge is up. It was a public holiday here so I was away for the long weekend.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Can you please update the featured tags? Remove it from this question and [the previous challenge](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2008/33442) and put it on the new one?

Comment: @linksassin done.  (I hadn't noticed we'd missed updating the previous challenge, oops.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks for doing that. I assume it just got missed since we took a week off.

Answer (score 2):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- Liquid, [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology), [Avoiding cliches when writing gods](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/avoiding-cliches-when-writing-gods)
- Liquid, [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative), [How do you show, through your narration, a hard and uncaring world?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/how-do-you-show-through-your-narration-an-hard-and-uncaring-world)
- NofP, related to the writing exercise, [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology)[character-development](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development)
  [Adding depth to two-dimensional heroes from myths](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45563/adding-depth-to-two-dimensional-heroes-from-myths)
- celtschk, [narrative](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narrative)[mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) [How to write a convincing religious myth?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/45834/5162)